# Can I use BIND to restrict certain zones to a limited set of IP addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I would like to have certain zones hosted by my DNS servers to be accessible internet-wide while restricting certain zones only to specific IP addresses (local or internet). Is this possible? How do I do it?

Putting the `allow-query { <ip.v4.ad.dr>; };` option in the `zone {...}` did not seem to stop me from fetching A records in that zones from IP addresses other than the one specified :-(

Comment: did you try `allow-query { <ip.v4.ad.dr>; !any; };`

Answer (score 1):

You could put the restricted zones in a separate bind view that is accessible only for the specific IP addresses. Check the manual for the exact configuration but basically you would define a view block and inside define a match-clients for your IPs and then another view with match-clients any.

Answer (score 0):

views are great but if the zone is not available in the public zone you can use zone level acl

```
acl trusted { 192.168.0.0/24; };
acl slaves { 192.168.1.10; 192.168.1.11; };
```

`allow-query { slaves; trusted; !any; };`

Answer (score -1):

Adding `allow-query{ trusted_ips; };` inside the `options` block in  `named.conf.options` worked for me.